# how to download web pages by submit a form?

Tags: java

I want to download a web page with a form, I need to fill this form and submit it and then get the return page, like this:

- http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Rebholz-srv/MeshUP/

When I fill the text area with **bone**, it will show some words in the text area, which is what I want. But my code can't finish this function, the following is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DownForm {
   public static void doSubmit(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
        URL siteUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        Set keys = data.keySet();
        Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator();
        String content = "";
        for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
            Object key = keyIter.next();
            if(i!=0) {
                content += "&";
            }
            content += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
        }
        System.out.println(content);
        out.writeBytes(content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("meshDataForm", "Pain and incapacity");
    try {
        doSubmit("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Rebholz-srv/MeshUP/", data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use `DataOutputStream`. Use the output stream directly.

Btw, it may be a lot easier for you to use [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/) or possibly [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to do that.